# Grails GSP accessing variables within script

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, gsp

I have searched for this but cannot seem to find the right solution. I am going to dumb down this a bit and see where I am going wrong.

I am using Grails for a project and I am really enjoying it. Where I think it is hard to get around is in the GSP's.

Can someone tell me given:

**Controller:**

```
def index()
{
   def message = "This is a test"
   [message: message]
}
```

Within the view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

             HOW DO YOU ACCESS THAT VARIABLE IN HERE 

        });

<body></body>
</html>
```

I am trying to feed some 3rd party javascript libs and I am having an issue trying to figure this out. Yes, I can manually ajax it or use the 3rd party library to call an ajax thingy. However, I thought there was a grails way for this so that I do not have to do so much heavy lifting. I mean are you pros out there accessing it above the script {} and making all things global? Just trying to figure out what the correct way of doing this is.

Example library I am using is the `JQwidgets` library which does have ajax calls, but I would rather pass in arrays and such directly into via named actions in Grails.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { var something = "${message}"; }` This assumes that the GSP that is being rendered is the view from the `index` controller method. That way the `model` in the `view` is available to the GSP when the page is compiled and rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var message = "${message}";
            console.log("I'm from GSP", message);
            $("input[selector]").val(message);    // Just a dumb example
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok that as that led me down the path to the answer.

The Key was to put the codec stmt at the top of the gsp.

I can't help think that I'm hacking this together. Whenever I code by "google" I find out that Im not following what a "pro" would do.
For now this seemed to solve this issue.

controller

```
def index() { 

    def configtree = ConfigTree.list()
    [message: configtree as JSON]
}


<%@page expressionCodec="none" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var data = ${raw(message)};

    // prepare the data
    var source =
    {
        datatype: "json",
        datafields: [
            { name: 'id' },
            { name: 'parentid' },
            { name: 'text' },
            { name: 'icon' },
            { name: 'expanded' },
            { name: 'selected' },
            { name: 'iconsize' },
            { name: 'disabled' },
            { name: 'value' }
        ],
        id: 'id',
        localdata: data
    };

    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    dataAdapter.dataBind();

    var records = dataAdapter.getRecordsHierarchy('id', 'parentid', 'items', [{ name: 'text', map: 'label'}]);
```

Comment: Always remember that the grails part is executed on the server, and the javascript on the browser. That's why you can't access grails variables form the view (nor javascript variables from grails code).
The comment of @joshua-moore is the way to do it.